# Updatepickerinput with change in pickerinput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to update the Pickerinput with change in another PickerInput.How can I do it in server side in Shiny?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give us more information and if possible a minimal reproducible example to allow us to help you.

Comment: I have two pickerInput with same choices as :choices = colnames(intangible_features[,c(30:34)]) .If user selects one option from pickerinput , another pickerinput get updated also on the same dashboard

Comment: As mentioned a code snippet containing a minimal reproducible example is best. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

You could use `observeEvent` function at the server side to monitor the status of `pickerInput` #1  then use `updatePickerInput` function to update `pickerInput` #2.

Please see the code below, which takes the first letter in  `pickerInput` #1 and chooses the content of `pickerInput` #2 accordingly:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Update pickerInput"),

  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 5, offset = 1,
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "p1",
        label = "Starting Letters",
        choices = LETTERS
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 5,
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "p2",
        label = "Names of Cars",
        choices = ""
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$p1, {
    updatePickerInput(session = session, inputId = "p2",
                      choices = grep(paste0("^",input$p1), rownames(mtcars), value = TRUE))

  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Output:
[image: example]